# scanf_s not working what is the error? can any one solve this

Tags: c, input, scanf, getchar

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int sum(), sub(), mul(), div();
    char ans;
    printf("\ta) Add\n");
    printf("\tb) Sub\n");
    printf("\tc) Multiply\n");
    printf("\td) Divition\n");
    scanf_s("%c",&ans);
    printf("\nYour answer is %c",ans);
    if((ans == 'A')||(ans == 'a'))
        printf("The sum of Two number is %d\n",sum());
    else if((ans == 'B')||(ans == 'b'))
        printf("The subraction of Two number is %d\n",sub());
    else if((ans == 'C')||(ans == 'c'))
        printf("The product of two number is %d\n",mul());
    else if((ans == 'D')||(ans == 'd'))
        printf("The divition of two number is %d\n",div());
    else
        printf("Enter the valid option\n");
}
int sum()
{
    int x,y;
    printf(" Addition\n");
    printf("Enter the first number = ");
    scanf_s("%d",&x);
    printf("Enter the second number = ");
    scanf_s("%d",&y);
    return x+y;
}
int sub()
{
    int x,y;
    printf(" Subraction\n");
    printf("Enter the first number = ");
    scanf_s("%d",&x);
    printf("Enter the second number = ");
    scanf_s("%d",&y);
    return x-y;
}
int mul()
{
    int x,y;
    printf(" Mltification\n");
    printf("Enter the first number = ");
    scanf_s("%d",&x);
    printf("Enter the second number = ");
    scanf_s("%d",&y);
    return x*y;
}
int div()
{
    int x,y;
    printf(" Divition\n");
    printf("Enter the first number = ");
    scanf_s("%d",&x);
    printf("ENter the second number = ");
    scanf_s("%d",&y);
    return x/y;
}
```

`scanf_s("%c",&ans);`

the function `scanf` does not recognize my input

whats wrong in the code

when i use 
`ans=getchar();` 
is working perfect but.. the `scanf` does not recognize what i input

can any one explain the problem in the code iam using visual studio 2010

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", &ans);` need size --> `scanf_s("%c", &ans, 1);`

Comment: This working thanks,.....

Comment: Per C11 §K.3.5.3.2, use `scanf_s("%c", &ans, (rsize_t) 1);` or `scanf_s("%c", &ans, sizeof ans );`

Answer (score 0):

To scan a single char you have to put a blank space before `%c`:

```
scanf(" %c", &char);
```

The blank space is needed to consume any `\n` char in the input buffer. You must put the blank space just for `char` type.

Comment: i got a answer scanf_s("%c", &ans, 1); thanks for answering